# Exchange 2007 mail.queue keeps growing then shuts down transport

Tags: exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, exchange

I have an exchange 2007 SP2 server where the Hub Transport log files, specifically the mail queue database keeps growing to 4GB, then the Exchange Transport service shuts down.

Once I delete the logs folder including the mail queue file, I can restart the transport server.

The problem is, it keeps growing to 4GB within 1 hour and the whole cycle repeats.

I'm looking for some advise on how to troubleshoot this. I've been trying many suggestions found on google however they all point to fixing the issue once, nothing about stopping it from reoccurring.

Thank you

Comment: What are the messages, and why are they sitting in the queue?  Are there log messages indicating back pressure for the transport service?

Comment: @ShaneMadden - I've been monitoring it with the Queue Viewer and their appears to be nothing strange in the queue, all small legitimate emails that are flowing succesfully.

Comment: Disk space issue?  Check out the following regarding "Back Pressure." http://blog.mattsampson.net/index.php/error_452_4_3_1_no_exchange_mail_being_s?blog=1

Comment: It's not an issue with back pressure, there's plenty of space on the drives.

Answer (score 1):

It would depend heavily on what is in the queue.  It's possible you're being spammed relentlessly.  It's also possible that you are receiving a lot of non-delivery notifications, or that you are sending nondelivery notifications to the queue.  In either of these cases, you might have a lot of nondeliverable mail in the queue, but depending on your configuration it may sit there for days until it is purged.

Check the hub transport logs.  They will tell you what it is thrashing about doing.

Comment: I am using an outside spam filtering service, 99% of spam never gets to my server, only legitimate email, and the queue does not appear to be flooded, as far as the queue viewer is reporting

Comment: Well, it's not going to write gibberish to the logs, or fill the queue with not mail.  What is in there?